# Regular expression to remove lines containing word with exceptions

Tags: regex

I am using this regex in PowerGrep, (this regex search for strings LAB RAD TRAN)

```
.*((LAB)|(RAD)|(TRAN)).*\r\n
```

to search and remove lines in plain text that contains strings or part of a string and it works great.

Now I need something more. I want to keep the word LABER, but remove every other string containing LAB, such as LABOR, LAB1, ALAB, ALABA, etc.
Is there a way to "protect" a string LABER and remove every other string containing LAB?
Tried to alter the above regex using `*` but it always includes the word LABER that I need to keep. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add exclusions to regex in the form by means of a look-ahead:

```
(?m)^.*(LAB(?!(?:ER|OV)\b)|RAD|TRAN).*$
```

The `(?!(?:ER|OV)\b)` lookahead will check if the sequence `LAB` is not followed by `ER` or `OV` and a word boundary.

I am adding the alternation into look-ahead because your ask to "protect" `LABER` and `LABOV`.

Also, since you are looking for whole lines, you can make use of the multiline mode `(?m)` and `^`/`$` anchors.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake in my question, I only want to keep the word LABER.

Comment: It is OK, now you know how to add alternatives to this regex. There is a problem with words like `ELABER`, but I hope there are no such words in your input.

Comment: You are welcome, please also consider upvoting the answer if it proved helpful (now, you have this privilege).

Comment: I used this solution and it works good, thanks. 
Now I tried to find solution to opposite problem,
Regex to sellect every line containing the string BALL, except the lines containing FOOTBALL, is that possible? I tried this:
.*(?<=foot)ball.*.*\r\n
but it didn't worked.

Comment: try `.*(?<!foot)ball.*` with case ignoring option.

Comment: Great, please consider upvoting my answer if it proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think PowerGrep supports lookaround assertions; if so, this should work:

```
.*((LAB(?!ER\b))|(RAD)|(TRAN)).*\r\n
```

Although that will keep anything ending with LABER, not just the whole word.

Comment: I was in the process of fixing that when you commented, @AndrisLeduskrasts.  It still excludes anything ending with -LABER, though.

Comment: That's an issue with OP's given solution though, as that goes for any of his words, `fooTRAN` for example. He could add a boundary before all the words too.